# Using existing hot water vent for extraction

Tags: hvac, boiler, ducts, hot-water, exhaust

[image]I have a room in the basement with equipment (computers) that gets really hot. There is an ac vent but the thermostat is nowhere near the room.

Also in an alcove is the hot water heater behind a louvered door.

I want to install an extractor fan essentially and create negative pressure in that alcove which will suck in the hot air and expel it outside through the existing hot water heater exhaust ducting. Putting a direct extractor outside I figured it would create back pressure and back draft, so how would I best connect an extraction system into the same ducting as the hot water heater. It vents directly outside the wall a little bit higher up in the space

Comment: Liquid-cool the computers and dump it into the cold water supply to the water heater. You've already paid for THAT electricity, might as well get some more use from it.

Comment: Not a good idea to mess with the balance of your hot water heater exhaust set up.

Comment: This is an *extremely* bad idea....perhaps rebalancing the A/C ducts in the basement is a better bet?

Comment: Almost certainly would be a code violation to employ the water heater vent for this purpose.

Comment: Can you post a photo of where water heater duct exits the house?

Comment: messing up the ventilation for a gas fueled heater is the kind of mistake you only make once. an opportunity best avoided.

Comment: So, what are my options for the space. It seems like even if I added more input in terms of ac airflow I may cause static pressure into the water heater? There is possibly another hole I can use to the outside but again this would cause negative pressure in the room...

Comment: I *think* Behind that second hole is also the chimney, I don't see brick  there but I do see it above in the

Comment: Is switching the WH out for a sealed combustion unit an option? That'd decouple it from the rest of the space at least, so you could add a thermostatic fan to your server room without it messing up the WH venting...

Comment: That could work, just a cost issue. If one attaches a fan inline with the existing duct to create negative pressure in that duct it would exhaust both the room and the heater... is there an issue with that? Does it have to be passive?